# Ember - How to display component name in the HTML

Tags: ember.js

when I'm working with an ember app, I would appreciate to see what component html I'm looking at. I know there is an Ember extension into the browser that can show me component names, but it would be much better to see it in the html. Something like this

```
<div id="ember282" class="ember-view">
  <!-- components/my-component -->
  <div id="ember317" class="ember-view">Component content</div>
  <!-- components/my-component end -->
</div>
```

is it possible? and how?

Thank you

Comment: You can taka a look at [ember-code-snippet](https://github.com/ef4/ember-code-snippet). Maybe it will help.

Comment: You could give your component a class

Comment: But then is stays there even when in production, and that's not what I want. And I would like to have something that's automatic.

Comment: You can put the comments with your component name within your `.hbs`...

Comment: I know, but that's not what I want. I would like it to be automatic and to make it work even on addon components that I don't have control over.